# Youtube gdata playlist httprequest

Tags: http, request, gdata

Hey I have a program which performs a GET request to YouTube for a JSON list of videos.

Whats is working: Perform a GET request to YouTube for a JSON list of all the videos by a specific user. The currently example url i am usings is :

Username is a variable i have set up.

```
    HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?orderby=published&author="+username+"&v=2&alt=jsonc");
```

What is not working: Perform a GET request to YouTube for a JSON list of all the videos by a specific playlist.

```
    HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlist/PL827BC9167705BBAB?alt=jsonc&v=2");
```

What is wrong with the playlist request ?

Comment: What exactly is the error message and the complete response you are getting?

Comment: It doesnt crash or give errors so i assume that something is wrong with the gdata url. The proplem is that it doesnt display videos like the user url